# can't get correct value for item return from DynamoDB in swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Trying to extract the value from DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue into either json or a string value... but not working.The connection and return data is working but I am getting updateDate : s("04/05/2022 06:04:84") as the return data. How do I parse the s("04/05/2022 06:04:84") into something that I can use, I can't seem to convert it to a String or a json structure.. Everything I try it says it can't convert from DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue

```
func getItemInTable(dynamoDbClient: DynamoDbClient, nameOfTable: String, key: String, keyVal: String) async throws {

let keyToGet = [key : DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue.s(keyVal)]
do {
   let results = try await dynamoDbClient.getItem(input: GetItemInput(key: keyToGet, tableName: nameOfTable))
   guard let numbersMap = results.item else {
       return
   }
    
    for returnedKey in numbersMap {
        print("\(returnedKey.key) : \(returnedKey.value)")
        }
        } catch {
            dump (error)
        }
```

}

Comment: If the attribute is a string then the returned attribute value has a property named `S` (for string). See [AttributeValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html). Not sure exactly how this is surfaced in the Swift SDK. Maybe `returnedKey.value.s()`? or similar.

Comment: Thanks jarmod... that sounds like it should but it doesn't like it.. I did add a switch that is working in for for loop but the returnedKey.value is still a problem getting it out

this is the entire results var
GetItemOutputResponse(consumedCapacity: nil, item: Optional(["stock": AWSDynamoDB.DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue.s("PRU"), "id": AWSDynamoDB.DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue.s("x345"), "updateDate": AWSDynamoDB.DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue.s("04/05/2022 06:04:84")]))

Comment: Just in case anyone else runs into this... Convert to json and then map to struct
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(returnedKey.value)
            if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
               print(jsonString)}